# Cross tabulation using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I define

```
$allRoles = array('musician', 'leader', 'singer'); // !important
```

above line dynamically [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200229/how-do-i-create-a-crosstab-table-with-php-mysql)? I mean to say `$allRoles` entities should come from MySQL table instead of define every entity here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: One of the answers on that link seems to answer the question, and use a database query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query =  "select role from user_role";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$allroles = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $allroles[] = $row['role'];
    }
```

print_r($allroles);